# python - Embedding Matplolib/Basemap in PyQt application

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am attempting to write a simple application which reads KML files and plots the data onto a Matplotlib/Basemap - sort of "poor's man Google Earth" which can be used offline for a quick view of the distribution of data over geographic space.

Currently, my problem is in embedding the Basemap into the user interface. The code below creates the application but instead of displaying the map, it only displays a pair of axes.

```
import warnings
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

class MyMplCanvas(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)
        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding,
                                   QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

        m = Basemap()
        m.drawcoastlines(color='#777799')
        m.drawcountries(color='#ccccee')
        m.drawmapboundary()
        m.bluemarble()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_DeleteOnClose)

        self.fileMenu = QtGui.QMenu("&File", self)
        self.fileMenu.addAction("Open...", self.fileOpen,
                                QtCore.Qt.CTRL + QtCore.Qt.Key_O)
        self.fileMenu.addSeparator()
        self.fileMenu.addAction("&Quit", self.fileQuit,
                                 QtCore.Qt.CTRL + QtCore.Qt.Key_Q)
        self.menuBar().addMenu(self.fileMenu)

        self.statusBar().setSizeGripEnabled(True)
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Ready")

        self.items = QtGui.QDockWidget("Layers", self)
        self.items.setFloating(False)
        self.items.setFeatures(self.items.NoDockWidgetFeatures)

        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget()
        self.listWidget.addItem("file1")
        self.listWidget.addItem("file2")
        self.listWidget.addItem("file3")      
        self.items.setWidget(self.listWidget)

        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        l = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        sc = MyMplCanvas(self.main_widget, width=5, height=4, dpi=100)
        l.addWidget(sc)
        self.main_widget.setFocus()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,650,350)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.LeftDockWidgetArea, self.items)
        self.setWindowTitle("Poor's Man KML Viewer")
        self.show()

    def fileOpen(self):
        filename = unicode(QtGui.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self, 
                        "Open file", "", 
                        "KML files (*.kml)"))
        if filename:
            self.listWidget.addItem(filename)

    def fileQuit(self):
        self.close()

    def closeEvent(self, ce):
        self.fileQuit()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

There are good examples of embedding Matplotlib plots into PyQt applications, but I could not find any considering Basemap.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say that you are missing to tell the basemap in which axes it should reside:

```
m = Basemap(..., ax=self.axes)
```

<sub>I would also suggest not to call a varaible by the name of a python function. I.e. use `m` instead of `map`.
 While this is unproblematic here, it is an easily overseen problem in other cases.</sub>

Without the use of the `ax` argument, Basemap would create its own figure or take the available matplotlib axes inside pyplot. Since in the embedded case, you do not want to use pyplot at all, a specific axes needs to be specified for the basemap to live in.

Comment: Thanks! In fact, I had just figured this out a few minutes ago! I edited the question to reflect your suggestions. BTW: Is there a way to make the map fill the whole area of the canvas? I did some experiments with tight_layout() but it changed nothing.

Comment: Note that this is a Question&Answer site. So giving the answer in the question may not make too much sense, especially when the answer is already given below it (in case it is not, you could of course answer your own question). Now the problem about `tight_layout` is not clear - where in the code is it? What is the problem using it etc.? There are two options: Edit this question to ask for the problem with `tight_layout` (although it is in general discouraged to change the meaning of a question after an answer is given as it renders the answer useless) or ask a new question about it.

Comment: My experiment with tight_layout is not implemented in this code. Anyway, I have already devised a potential solution. Thanks!